# Recursive Floodfill error in Javascript - doesn't keep recursing?

Tags: javascript, recursion, flood-fill

I'm new-ish to using Javascript and am trying to code a floodfill-type algorithm in it for the first time (using the p5js library specifically). This is my first time with recursion in Javascript.

I've implemented floodfill in python in the past and that worked fine. I figured that I could use the same code but change the syntax but it's not working for me.

It begins filling in around the obstacles but then it stops in the middle and I can't tell why

```
function generatePaths(board, row, col, depth=0){
    //print(board[row][col][1]);
    if ((row<0) || (row>100) || (col<0) || (col>100)){
        return;
    }
    if (board[row][col][0]!=0){
        return;
    }
    if (board[row][col][1]>0) {
        return;
    }
    if (board[row][col][0] == 0){
        board[row][col][0] = 2;
        board[row][col][1] = depth;
    }
    generatePaths(board, row+1,col, depth+1);
    generatePaths(board, row-1,col, depth+1);
    generatePaths(board, row,col-1, depth+1);
    generatePaths(board, row,col-1, depth+1);
}
```

I think the row and col variables are probably self explanatory. The third index represents the value and depth of the recursion. I originally didn't have a depth value but I was worried that could be the problem so I added it (it didn't change anything)

I want to replace all the empty board[row][col][0] values with 2s. They are empty if theres a 0 there currently. The place I keep getting an error is at the first recursive call

I might be making a dumb mistake but I can't find it if that's the case! I don't understand what is going on with this error, help is appreciated!!

Here's a picture of what it's doing. I don't know why it just stops.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1J9G.png)

Comment: Okay I figured out why I was getting the error (100 was too much so i changed my bounds to row>99 and col>99) Unfortunately though, it's still not recursing and now I really have no idea why

Comment: first, your snippet is missing `row,col+1`. Second, did you check the dev-tools I'd guess that you get an too much recursion error. And just a hint, instead of storing/passing the depth a better property to pass would be the direction from wich you came (just 1,2,3,4) as it is pointless to move back to the field you just came from: `if(direction !== 2) generatePaths(board, row+1,col, 1); if(direction !== 1) generatePaths(board, row+1,col, 2);` ...

Answer (score 0):

The main problem while doing flood fill algorithm using `javascript` is the recursion call-stack which cannot handle large stack recursion that's why the code needs to be converted to loop and array variant which uses heap to run the algorithm. The link below will brief out the idea as well as the logic behind the heap variant.

[flood-fill-algorithm-without-recursion](https://dev.to/codeguppy/flood-fill-recursion-or-no-recursion-3fop)